# React Getting error props.auth.data.map not a function after use modal to create a record. Record is added but I need to reload the page to see result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

The parent component is a table that shows all the records I have for members in a table. I fetch that data from an API in django. I have a modal that allows me to create a new member. I am able to create the new member but then it crashes and give me an error that
`props.auth.data.map` is not a function. If I reload the page then it will show me the new record in the table.

MemberList.js

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Member from "./Member"
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import { MemberContext } from "../contexts/MemberContext";
import { Modal , Button} from "react-bootstrap";
import AddForm from "./AddForm";
import { connect, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { memberList } from '../actions/auth';

const MemberList = (props) => {
    const { members } = useContext(MemberContext)
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    // const member = useSelector((state) => state.contr);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
      props.fetchmembers();
      // memberList()
      handleClose();
    }, [])

    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    //test = Array.from(props.auth.data);

    return props.auth.loading?(
        <h2>Loading</h2>
    ): props.auth.error? 
    (
        <h2>{props.auth.error}</h2>
    ):(
        <>
            <div className="table-title">
                <div className="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h2>Manage <b>Members</b></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-sm-6">
                    <Button onClick={handleShow} className="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"><i className="material-icons">&#xE147;</i> <span>Add New Member</span></Button>                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Table striped bordered hover>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>MemberID</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>State</th>
                        <th>Zip Code</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        props.auth && props.auth.data &&
                      props.auth.data.map(item => (
                            <tr key={item.id}>
                                <Member item={item} />
                            </tr>
                        ))
                    }

                </tbody>
            </Table>

            <Modal show={show}  onHide={handleClose}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>
                        Add Member
                    </Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <AddForm/>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button onClick={handleClose} variant="secondary">
                        Close
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    auth: state.auth
});

const mapDispatchtoprops = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchmembers: () => dispatch(memberList())
    }
}

//export default MemberList
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchtoprops)(MemberList)
```

Member.js

```
import { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import MemberContext from "../contexts/MemberContext";
import { Modal , Button} from "react-bootstrap";
import EditForm from "./EditForm";

const Member = ({item}) => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    
    return(
        <>
            <td>{item.memberID}</td>
            <td>{item.first_name}</td>
            <td>{item.last_name}</td>
            <td>{item.address}</td>
            <td>{item.city}</td>
            <td>{item.state}</td>
            <td>{item.zip_code}</td>
            <td>{item.email}</td>
            <td>{item.phone}</td>
            <td><button onClick={handleShow} href="#editEmployeeModal" className="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i className="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></button>
                <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" className="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i className="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
            </td>
            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>
                Edit Member
            </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
            <EditForm theMember={item} />
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                    Close Button
                </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
        </>
    )
}

export default Member
```

AddForm.js

```
import { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap"
import { MemberContext } from "../contexts/MemberContext";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addNewMember } from '../actions/auth';

const AddForm = ({ addNewMember }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    memberID: '',
    first_name: '',
    last_name: '',
    address: '',
    city: '',
    state: '',
    zip_code: '',
    email: '',
    phone: ''
  });
  const { memberID, first_name,last_name,address,city,state,zip_code, email, phone } = formData;

  const onChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });


  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
       addNewMember(memberID, first_name, last_name, address, city, state, zip_code, email,phone);
  };

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
      <Form.Group>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          placeholder="MemberID *"
          name="memberID"
          value={memberID}
          onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          required
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <br/>
      <Form.Group>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          placeholder="First Name *"
          name="first_name"
          value={first_name}
          onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          required
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <br/>
      <Form.Group>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          placeholder="Last Name *"
          name="last_name"
          value={last_name}
          onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          required
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <br/>
      <Form.Group>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          placeholder="Address *"
          name="address"
          value={address}
          onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          required
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <br/>
      <Form.Group>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          placeholder="City *"
          name="city"
          value={city}
          onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          required
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <br/>
      <Form.Group>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          placeholder="State *"
          name="state"
          value={state}
          onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          required
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <br/>
      <Form.Group>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          placeholder="Zip Code *"
          name="zip_code"
          value={zip_code}
          onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          required
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <br/>
      <Form.Group>
        <Form.Control
          type="email"
          placeholder="Email *"
          name="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          required
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <br/>
      <Form.Group>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          placeholder="Phone *"
          name="phone"
          value={phone}
          onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          required
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <br/>
      <Button variant="success" type="submit" block> 
        Add new Member
      </Button>
    </Form>
  )
}

//export default AddForm;
export default connect(null, { addNewMember })(AddForm);
```

store.js

```js
import { applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';
import auth from './reducers/auth';
import contr from './reducers/contr';
import { legacy_createStore as createStore } from 'redux';

const composeEnhancers = (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) || compose

const reducers = combineReducers({
    auth: auth, 
    contr: contr, 
});

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
    reducers, 
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)),
)

export default store;
```

auth.js  (reducer)

```js
import {
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_FAIL,
    USER_LOADED_SUCCESS,
    USER_LOADED_FAIL,
    AUTHENTICATED_SUCCESS,
    AUTHENTICATED_FAIL,
    PASSWORD_RESET_SUCCESS,
    PASSWORD_RESET_FAIL,
    PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_SUCCESS,
    PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_FAIL,
    SIGNUP_SUCCESS,
    SIGNUP_FAIL,
    ACTIVATION_SUCCESS,
    ACTIVATION_FAIL,
    MEMBER_LIST_SUCCESS,
    MEMBER_LIST_FAIL,
    MEMBER_LIST_REQUEST,
    MEMBER_ADD_SUCCESS,
    MEMBER_ADD_FAIL,
    LOGOUT
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    access: localStorage.getItem('access'),
    refresh: localStorage.getItem('refresh'),
    isAuthenticated: null,
    user: null,
    data: [],
    error: '',
    hasError: false,
    loading: true
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch(type) {
        case AUTHENTICATED_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true
            }
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            localStorage.setItem('access', payload.access);
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                access: payload.access,
                refresh: payload.refresh,
                hasError: false,
                
            }
        case USER_LOADED_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                user: payload,
                hasError: false,
                
            }
        case SIGNUP_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                hasError: false ,
                
                }
        case MEMBER_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return{
                ...state,
                        
                loading: false,
                data: action.payload,
                error: ''
                    }
        case MEMBER_LIST_REQUEST:
            return{
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
            case MEMBER_ADD_SUCCESS:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    
                    loading: false,
                    data: action.payload,
                    error: ''
                }
        case MEMBER_LIST_FAIL:
            return {
                loading: false,
                data:[],
                error: action.payload
                        }
        case USER_LOADED_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                user: null
            }
        case AUTHENTICATED_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: false
                }
        case SIGNUP_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                hasError: true,
                

            }
        case LOGOUT:
                localStorage.removeItem('access');
                localStorage.removeItem('refresh');
            return {
                ...state,
                access: null,
                refresh: null,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                user: null
                    }
        case LOGIN_FAIL:
                localStorage.removeItem('access');
                localStorage.removeItem('refresh');
            return {
                    ...state,
                    access: null,
                    refresh: null,
                    isAuthenticated: false,
                    user: null,
                    hasError: true,
                    
                }
        case MEMBER_ADD_FAIL:
            return {
                loading: false,
                data:[],
                error: action.payload
            }
        case PASSWORD_RESET_SUCCESS:
        case PASSWORD_RESET_FAIL:
        case PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_SUCCESS:
        case PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_FAIL:
        case ACTIVATION_SUCCESS:
        case ACTIVATION_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state
            }
        default:
                return state
    }
}
```

auth.js (actions)

```js
export const addNewMember = (memberID, first_name, last_name, address, city, state, zip_code, email, phone) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({ memberID, first_name, last_name, address, city, state,zip_code,email,phone });

    try {
        const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/member/`, body, config);

        dispatch({
            type: MEMBER_ADD_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        });
        toast.success('Check your Email to verify Account');
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: MEMBER_ADD_FAIL
        })
    }
};

const memberListRequest = () => {
    return {
        type: MEMBER_LIST_REQUEST
    }
}

const memberListSuccess = (data) => {
    return {
        type: MEMBER_LIST_SUCCESS,
        payload: data
    }
}

const memberListFailure = (err) => {
    return {
        type: MEMBER_LIST_FAIL,
        payload: err
    }
}

export const memberList = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(memberListRequest);
        axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/member/`).then(res=>{
            let _list=res.data
            dispatch(memberListSuccess(_list))
        }).catch(err=>{
            dispatch(memberListFailure(err.message))
        })
    }
}
```

Payload from MEMBER_ADD_SUCCESS

```
type(pin): "MEMBER_ADD_SUCCESS"
id(pin): 19
memberID(pin): "18"
first_name(pin): "John"
last_name(pin): "Doe"
address(pin): "123 Manchester"
city(pin): "SI"
state(pin): "NY"
zip_code(pin): "10312"
email(pin): "John@gmail.com"
phone(pin): "1112345556"
```

Payload for MEMBER_LIST_SUCCESS

```
type(pin): "MEMBER_LIST_SUCCESS"
id(pin): 1
memberID(pin): "80"
first_name(pin): "Jose"
last_name(pin): "Padilla"
address(pin): "29 Gibson Dr"
city(pin): "Hazlet"
state(pin): "NJ"
zip_code(pin): "07730"
email(pin): "quito1970@gmail.com"
phone(pin): "917-324-5844"
id(pin): 2
memberID(pin): "1"
first_name(pin): "Pedro"
last_name(pin): "Padilla"
address(pin): "35 Gibson Dr"
city(pin): "Hazlet"
state(pin): "NJ"
zip_code(pin): "07730"
email(pin): "quito1971@gmail.com"
phone(pin): "917-324-5845"
```

Payload MEMBER_ADD_SUCCESS

```json
{"memberID":"19","first_name":"Jane","last_name":"Doe","address":"1 Liberty St","city":"Red Bank","state":"NJ","zip_code":"07748","email":"Jane@bny.com","phone":"980-789-0987"}
```

Response

```json
{
    "id": 20,
    "memberID": "19",
    "first_name": "Jane",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "address": "1 Liberty St",
    "city": "Red Bank",
    "state": "NJ",
    "zip_code": "07748",
    "email": "Jane@bny.com",
    "phone": "980-789-0987"
}
```

MEMBER_LIST_SUCCESS

Preview

```
[{id: 1, memberID: "80", first_name: "Jose", last_name: "Padilla", address: "29 Gibson Dr",…},…]
0
: 
{id: 1, memberID: "80", first_name: "Jose", last_name: "Padilla", address: "29 Gibson Dr",…}
address
: 
"29 Gibson Dr"
city
: 
"Hazlet"
email
: 
"quito1970@gmail.com"
first_name
: 
"Jose"
id
: 
1
last_name
: 
"Padilla"
memberID
: 
"80"
phone
: 
"917-324-5844"
state
: 
"NJ"
zip_code
: 
"07730"
1
: 
{id: 2, memberID: "1", first_name: "Pedro", last_name: "Padilla", address: "35 Gibson Dr",…}
2
: 
{id: 3, memberID: "34", first_name: "Sandro", last_name: "Escobar", address: "1 Portacarrero Pl",…}
3
: 
{id: 4, memberID: "16", first_name: "Luke", last_name: "Padilla", address: "56 Gibson Dr",…}
```

Response

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "memberID": "80",
        "first_name": "Jose",
        "last_name": "Padilla",
        "address": "29 Gibson Dr",
        "city": "Hazlet",
        "state": "NJ",
        "zip_code": "07730",
        "email": "quito1970@gmail.com",
        "phone": "917-324-5844"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "memberID": "1",
        "first_name": "Pedro",
        "last_name": "Padilla",
        "address": "35 Gibson Dr",
        "city": "Hazlet",
        "state": "NJ",
        "zip_code": "07730",
        "email": "quito1971@gmail.com",
        "phone": "917-324-5845"
    }
]
```

Comment: The action payloads for `MEMBER_LIST_SUCCESS` or `MEMBER_ADD_SUCCESS` are ***not*** what you expect them to be when they update the `state.auth.data` state value. Check these response and payload values to ensure you are maintaining a proper state invariant. Can you [edit] the post to include what these values are? See [mcve].

Comment: Hi, I added the payload I get from MEMBER_ADD_SUCCESS and MEMBER_LIST_SUCCESS.

Comment: That looks like output from the Redux Devtools extension, and they appear to be objects, not arrays. Sorry if it was unclear, but we meant to share what the API response value is from the network tab, and to basically console log what the `axios.post` and `axios.get` response values are in the code, e.g. what is passed to the actions as payloads.

Comment: Hi, Sorry I hope this time I provided the information you need. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mismatch of the response value between two of the API endpoints you are using. When you reload the page the GET request is made and the response value that is an array is used, but when adding a member, the POST response value is an object and replaces the array value that was in state.

The `MEMBER_LIST_SUCCESS` action is passed an array of objects:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "memberID": "80",
    "first_name": "Jose",
    "last_name": "Padilla",
    "address": "29 Gibson Dr",
    "city": "Hazlet",
    "state": "NJ",
    "zip_code": "07730",
    "email": "quito1970@gmail.com",
    "phone": "917-324-5844"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "memberID": "1",
    "first_name": "Pedro",
    "last_name": "Padilla",
    "address": "35 Gibson Dr",
    "city": "Hazlet",
    "state": "NJ",
    "zip_code": "07730",
    "email": "quito1971@gmail.com",
    "phone": "917-324-5845"
   }
]
```

While the `MEMBER_ADD_SUCCESS` action is passed an object:

```json
{
  "id": 20,
  "memberID": "19",
  "first_name": "Jane",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "address": "1 Liberty St",
  "city": "Red Bank",
  "state": "NJ",
  "zip_code": "07748",
  "email": "Jane@bny.com",
  "phone": "980-789-0987"
}
```

`MEMBER_ADD_SUCCESS` appears to just be the member object that was added instead of the entire array of members with it included. Update the `MEMBER_ADD_SUCCESS` reducer case to append this value to the current `state.auth.data` array.

Example:

```js
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch(type) {
    ...

    case MEMBER_LIST_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        data: payload, // <-- entire array
        error: ''
      }

    ...

    case MEMBER_ADD_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        // append and return new array
        data: state.data.concat(payload), // <-- maintain array invariant
        // or data: [...state.data, payload],
        error: ''
      }

     ...

     default:
       return state;
  }
};
```